# C# check if element exists in xml where attribute

Tags: c#, sql, xml, function, parsing

I need to check my XML document if a certain element exists with the name

```
channel-category
```

where element attribute equals certain id

```
channel id="X"
```

I have the following function but it's always returning false even though it does exist

```
static bool exists(string channelname)
    {
        string path;
        string xmlfile = "\\xmlfile.xml";
        path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + xmlfile;
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path);

        bool doesexists = (from data in xmlDoc.Element("tv").Elements("channel").Elements("channel-category")
                       where (string)data.Attribute("id") == channelname
                       select data).Any();
        return doesexists;
    }
```

here is an example of my xml

```
<tv info="blahblah">
  <channel id="Channelname1">
    <display-name lang="en">Channelname1</display-name>
    <icon src="somelogo.png" />
    <url>http://somelink.com</url>
    <channel-category>SomeValue</channel-category>
  </channel>
  <channel id="Channelname2">
    <display-name lang="en">Channelname2</display-name>
    <icon src="somelogo.png" />
    <url>http://somelink.com</url>
   </channel>
</tv>
```

Now the function should return true for id Channelname1 but false for id Channelname2 but it's just returning false for both of them and I'm not sure why. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with **HaukurHaf**, alternatively you could also write simple `Linq` statement as shown below.

```
static bool exists(string channelname) 
{
    string path;
    string xmlfile = "\\xmlfile.xml";
    path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + xmlfile;
    XmlDocument doc = XmlDocument.Load(path);

     return (doc.Descendants("channel").Any(x => (string) x.Attribute("id") == channelname && x.Element("channel-category") != null);
}
```

Try this working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L2Lgsv)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use XDocument and Linq2Xml ?
How about using the XmlDocument class and XPath?

```
static bool exists(string channelname)
    {
        string path;
        string xmlfile = "\\xmlfile.xml";
        path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + xmlfile;
        XmlDocument doc = XmlDocument.Load(path);

        return doc.SelectSingleNode("//tv/channel[@id=" + channelname + "]/channel-category") != null;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! unfortunately it's still returning false.
`if (exists(allchannels))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("already exists!");
                        }
                        else`

the function returns false and hits the else

  `string.Concat returned "//tv/channel[@id=Channelname1]/channel-category" string
  System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode returned null System.Xml.XmlNode
  channelname "Channelname1" string`